# How to update a record using Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

How can I convert this code to Entity Framework?

```
update cachieroperation set last_used = getdate()+'0:8:0' where id = 14
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Should be something like(I don't know what your classes are called):

```
using(var context = new SomeEntities())
{
     CarrierOperation carrierOperation = context.CarrierOperations.SingleOrDefault(co=> co.id == 14);
     if(carrierOperation != null)
     {
         carrierOperation.last_used = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(8);
         context.SaveChanges();
     }
}
```

Comment: This answer execute a SELECT, loads all data of record (transfer from DB to application) then executes the update. I have suggested a duplicate on the question to use object model but only execute the UPDATE

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ExecuteQuery` for executing queries directly against the database:

```
string query = "update cachieroperation set last_used = getdate()+'0:8:0' where id = 14";
context.ExecuteQuery<cachieroperation>(query );
```

For more info, see [Microsoft Docs on `ExecuteQuery`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.linq.datacontext.executequery)